# Interpolate Color in GLSL Raytracer

Tags: colors, glsl, raytracing

I'm trying to interpolate the color between 4 points on a sphere, which I traced in the fragment shader. I know that I have to give each ray a specific color and I know how to interpolate the color. My problem is that I don't know how I set a specific color to a specific ray.

Here:

[image: img]

is an image of my scene. The corners of the patch should be red(bottom left), green(top left), blue (top right) and yellow (bottom right) with interpolated colors in between.

Here is my fragment shader code.

```
// FragmentProgram
#version 430

layout(location=0) out vec4 FragColor;
layout (std430, binding=3) buffer passColor
{
  float ssbo_Color[];
};
layout (std430, binding=4) buffer points
{
  float ssbo_Points[];
};

uniform vec3 camera_position;  

in vec3 ray_entry_point;

struct GridPoints
{
    vec3 p0;
    vec3 c0;
    vec3 p1;
    vec3 c1;
    vec3 p2;
    vec3 c2;
    vec3 p3;
    vec3 c3;
};

vec4 sph1 = vec4 (-2.0, 1.4, 0.0, 1.4);
vec4 sph2 = vec4 (2.0, 1.4, 0.0, 1.4);
GridPoints g;

float iSphere(in vec3 ro, in vec3 rd, in vec4 sph)
{
    vec3 o2c = ro - sph.xyz;
    float b = 2.0* dot(o2c, rd);
    float c = dot(o2c,o2c) - sph.w*sph.w;
    float h = b*b - 4.0*c;

    if (h<0.0){
        return -1.0;
    }
    float t = (-b - sqrt(h)) / 2.0;
    return t;
}

float iPlane(in vec3 ro, in vec3 rd)
{
    return -ro.y  / ( rd.y) ;
}

vec3 nPlane (in vec3 pos)
{
    return vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}

float intersect(in vec3 ro, in vec3 rd, out float resT)
{
    resT = 10000000.0;
    float id = -1.0;
    float tsph1 = iSphere(ro, rd, sph1);
    float tsph2 = iSphere(ro, rd, sph2);
    float tpla = iPlane(ro, rd);

    if( tsph1 > 0.0){
        id = 1.0;
        resT = tsph1;
    }
    if( tsph2 > 0.0){
        id = 1.0;
        resT = tsph2;
    }
    if ( tpla > 0.0 && tpla < resT){
        id = 2.0;
        resT = tpla;
    }

    return id;
}

void main()
{
    vec3 light_pos = normalize(vec3(0.0,0.0,-1.0));
    vec4 col = vec4(0.2);

    vec3 ro = ray_entry_point + vec3(0.0,0.5,0.0);
    vec3 rd = -normalize(camera_position - ray_entry_point );
    float t;

    float id = intersect(ro, rd, t);
    // Test Points
    g.p0.x = ssbo_Points[0];
    g.p0.y = ssbo_Points[1];
    g.p0.z = ssbo_Points[2];

    g.p1.x = ssbo_Points[168];
    g.p1.y = ssbo_Points[169];
    g.p1.z = ssbo_Points[170];

    g.p2.x = ssbo_Points[168+3];
    g.p2.y = ssbo_Points[169+3];
    g.p2.z = ssbo_Points[170+3];

    g.p3.x = ssbo_Points[3];
    g.p3.y = ssbo_Points[4];
    g.p3.z = ssbo_Points[5];


    vec3 d = (g.p0+g.p1+g.p2+g.p3)/4; //Vector to midpoint of patch
    vec3 dc = d - sph1.xyz; // Vector to sphere center
    vec3 d_true = d -(sqrt(pow(sph1.w,2))-sqrt(pow(dc.x,2)+ pow(dc.y,2)+pow(dc.z,2))); // Real vector to midpoint of patch

    vec3 patch_col;
    vec3 pos;
    // Test Colors
    g.c0 = vec3(1,0,0);
    g.c1 = vec3(0,1,0);
    g.c2 = vec3(0,0,1);
    g.c3 = vec3(1,1,0);

    if( id > 0.0 && id < 1.5) {
        // hit sphere
        pos = ro + t*rd;
        col = vec4 (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1);
        if(abs(pos.y) > abs(g.p0.y) && abs(pos.y) < abs(g.p1.y) &&
           abs(pos.x) < abs(g.p0.x) && abs(pos.x) > abs(g.p2.x)){

            pos = ro + t*rd;
            // Interpolated Color
            patch_col = g.c0 + (g.c1-g.c0)/(g.p1.y-g.p0.y)*(pos.y-g.p1.y);

            col = vec4(patch_col,1);
        }
    }
    else if ( id > 1.5){
        // hit plane
        vec3 pos = ro + t*rd ;

        vec3 nor_L = nPlane(pos);
        float dif_L = clamp(dot( nor_L, light_pos), 0.0, 1.0);
        float amb_L = smoothstep(0.0, sph1.w, length(pos.xz-sph1.xz));

        vec3 nor_R = nPlane(pos);
        float dif_R = clamp(dot( nor_R, light_pos), 0.0, 1.0);
        float amb_R = smoothstep(0.0, sph2.w, length(pos.xz-sph2.xz));

        col = vec4(vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2) * amb_R*amb_L ,1.0);
    }
    FragColor = col;
}
```

Any hint would help.

Comment: I'm passing the point positions and the colors via ssbos. The whole scene is created by raytracing. The only vertices I pass through the vertex shader are from a cube in witch I raytrace my scene.

Comment: Can you turn your code in a Shadertoy (https://www.shadertoy.com/) example? This would give us a minimal, verifiable example and a better chance to help you